# light goes through walls - Unity HDRP

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, lighting

I'm making a game with realtime lighting in HDRP and i don't know why i have tried so many things but the light just goes through walls and things.

i don't know what is going on.
please help me

if you need more images or things just tell me and i'll give them

[image: the light going through a wall]

[image: the light going through a primitive cube]

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you tried baking the lighting since you added the walls? Could be highlights baked onto the textures.

Comment: I'm with realtime ilumination only.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got It fixed by enabling shadow map on my Light source.

Comment: Elaborate on how to do that more specifically please.